# How to create spoon of hammerspoon in right way?

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I wrote a spoon script to control volume, but the `hotkeys.bind` method doesn't work, what is the problem?

Here is the `init.lua` of the spoon

```lua
-- === Volume ===

local obj={}
obj.__index = obj

-- Metadata
obj.name = "Volume"
obj.version = "1.0"
obj.license = "MIT - https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"

obj.logger = hs.logger.new('Volume')

function obj:init()
end

function obj:changeVolume(diff)
   return function()
     local current = hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():volume()
     local new = math.min(100, math.max(0, math.floor(current + diff)))
     if new > 0 then
       hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():setMuted(false)
     end
     hs.alert.closeAll(0.0)
     hs.alert.show("Volume " .. new .. "%", {}, 0.5)
     hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():setVolume(new)
   end
 end

return obj
```

I loaded and used this spoon in `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` by

```lua
hs.loadSpoon("Volume")
hs.hotkey.bind({'cmd', 'alt'}, '[', function() spoon.Volume:changeVolume(-3) end)
hs.hotkey.bind({'cmd', 'alt'}, ']', function() spoon.Volume:changeVolume(3) end)
```

Answer (score 3):

When the `changeVolume` method is called it *returns* a function, but does not *execute* it. The only thing you need to do to make it work is to remove second line from top and bottom, this way when the function is called it will be executed:

```lua
function obj:changeVolume(diff)
    local current = hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():volume()
    local new = math.min(100, math.max(0, math.floor(current + diff)))
    if new > 0 then
        hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():setMuted(false)
    end
    hs.alert.closeAll(0.0)
    hs.alert.show("Volume " .. new .. "%", {}, 0.5)
    hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():setVolume(new)
 end
```

Note that the [suggested](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/blob/master/SPOONS.md#hotkeys) way is to expose a `:bindHotKeys()` method. I'd recommend to make the `changeVolume` function local (`local function changeVolume`) and then expose `inc()` and `dec()` methods:

```lua
local function changeVolume(diff)
...
end

function obj:inc()
    changeVolume(3)
end

function obj:dec()
    changeVolume(-3)
end

function obj:bindHotkeys(mapping)
    local spec = {
        inc = hs.fnutils.partial(self.inc, self),
        dec = hs.fnutils.partial(self.dec, self),
      }
      hs.spoons.bindHotkeysToSpec(spec, mapping)
      return self
end
```